# LWJGL 3 GLFW keyboard and mouse input is slow and has a delay between GLFW_PRESS and GLFW_REPEAT

Tags: java, opengl, user-input, lwjgl, glfw

So I have just recently moved from LWJGL 2 to 3, and I am having a bit of difficulty with getting keyboard and mouse input. I am using this for camera movement and rotation, by the way.

My problem is that if I use the GLFW callbacks, the movement seems very choppy and slow. It isn't a consistent speed, and just doesn't feel right. Furthermore, when I press a key, for example w to move forward, there is about a half-second delay between the transition from `GLFW_PRESS` to `GLFW_REPEAT` This causes the camera to not move for the first half a second when the key is pressed.

By the way, I have a InputHandler class that has methods for keyDown, keyPressed, keyReleased, etc. I do not have all of the key checks in the one invoke method.The invoke method adds the key events to a list which stores the key, and an event state enum that can be one of DOWN, TAPPED, RELEASED, NONE. The class is heavily based on the response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20053847/problems-with-single-tap-and-press-and-hold-with-lwjgl?answertab=active#tab-top)

I have spent the past 2 hours trying to find a solution for this, and haven't found much. I did find some people using an alternative method to the callbacks though, like so:

```
if (glfwGetKey(window, key) == GLFW_PRESS)
```

and

```
if (glfwGetKey(windowm key) == GLFW_RELEASE)
```

But I cant find a way to use this to detect a single key tap, i.e. the `GLFW_REPEAT` state, because the `glfwGetKey` method can only detect `GLFW_PRESS` and `GLFW_RELEASE`.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could tell me a way of either detecting a single key tap with the `glfwGetKey` method, or making the GLFW callbacks much less laggy, and more smooth.

Thanks :)

Comment: Presumably, if you're animating (using `glfwPollEvents` in a loop), you can assume the key is held down until your key handler callback receives a `RELEASE` for that key. Otherwise, `glfwWaitEvents` in a loop isn't going to do anything until the window system decides a long enough interval for `REPEAT` has transpired.

Comment: Is there a way to shorten the time it takes to register a `GLFW_REPEAT`?

Comment: Not using glfw. There may be OS-dependent ways to do this, but glfw only responds to events as provided by the OS. And I suspect it would have a global effect, rather than per-application.

Comment: Okay. Well I managed to get your suggestion of assuming the key is down until a `GLFW_RELEASE` event is fired. It works, and I'll post my working InputHandler class, Thankyou :)

Answer (score 6):

So I solved the problem, thanks to Brett Hale's suggestion of assuming that the key is down until a `GLFW_RELEASE` event is fired. This is my working implementation of this:

```
public final class InputHandler
{
    private static long window;
    private static final int KEYBOARD_SIZE = 512;
    private static final int MOUSE_SIZE = 16;

    private static int[] keyStates = new int[KEYBOARD_SIZE];
    private static boolean[] activeKeys = new boolean[KEYBOARD_SIZE];

    private static int[] mouseButtonStates = new int[MOUSE_SIZE];
    private static boolean[] activeMouseButtons = new boolean[MOUSE_SIZE];
    private static long lastMouseNS = 0;
    private static long mouseDoubleClickPeriodNS = 1000000000 / 5; //5th of a second for double click.

    private static int NO_STATE = -1;


    protected static GLFWKeyCallback keyboard = new GLFWKeyCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void invoke(long window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
        {
            activeKeys[key] = action != GLFW_RELEASE;
            keyStates[key] = action;
        }
    };

    protected static GLFWMouseButtonCallback mouse = new GLFWMouseButtonCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void invoke(long window, int button, int action, int mods)
        {
            activeMouseButtons[button] = action != GLFW_RELEASE;
            mouseButtonStates[button] = action;
        }
    };

    protected static void init(long window)
    {
        InputHandler.window = window;

        resetKeyboard();
        resetMouse();
    }

    protected static void update()
    {
        resetKeyboard();
        resetMouse();

        glfwPollEvents();
        Engine.getInput();
    }

    private static void resetKeyboard()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < keyStates.length; i++)
        {
            keyStates[i] = NO_STATE;
        }
    }

    private static void resetMouse()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < mouseButtonStates.length; i++)
        {
            mouseButtonStates[i] = NO_STATE;
        }

        long now = System.nanoTime();

        if (now - lastMouseNS > mouseDoubleClickPeriodNS)
            lastMouseNS = 0;
    }

    public static boolean keyDown(int key)
    {
        return activeKeys[key];
    }

    public static boolean keyPressed(int key)
    {
        return keyStates[key] == GLFW_PRESS;
    }

    public static boolean keyReleased(int key)
    {
        return keyStates[key] == GLFW_RELEASE;
    }

    public static boolean mouseButtonDown(int button)
    {
        return activeMouseButtons[button];
    }

    public static boolean mouseButtonPressed(int button)
    {
        return mouseButtonStates[button] == GLFW_RELEASE;
    }

    public static boolean mouseButtonReleased(int button)
    {
        boolean flag = mouseButtonStates[button] == GLFW_RELEASE;

        if (flag)
            lastMouseNS = System.nanoTime();

        return flag;
    }

    public static boolean mouseButtonDoubleClicked(int button)
    {
        long last = lastMouseNS;
        boolean flag = mouseButtonReleased(button);

        long now = System.nanoTime();

        if (flag && now - last < mouseDoubleClickPeriodNS)
        {
            lastMouseNS = 0;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Feel free to use this code if you want to. Just some notes though: the update method should be called every frame. Also, if you have the `glfwPollEvents()` somewhere else, which I think is likely, than you need to keep the order of reset keyboard/mouse, then poll, then getinput().

Edit:
My `Engine.getInput()` methos is just what tells nodes in the scene graph that require input, i.e. the player, to query that input.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. I am still very new to GLFW and OpenGL 3, so I haven't seen `glfwWaitEvents()` before. I followed [this guide](https://www.lwjgl.org/guide) to set up my window. Where should `glfwWaitEvents()` be??!

Answer (score 6):

While Kelan's answer works perfectly, I thought I would share my solution to this as I ran into the same issue while working on a game. I implemented my own Keyboard class and included the following methods

```
public static boolean isKeyPressed(int key)
{
    return (GLFW.glfwGetKey(Game.window.handle, key) == KEY_PRESS);
}

public static boolean isKeyReleased(int key)
{
    return (GLFW.glfwGetKey(Game.window.handle, key) == KEY_RELEASE);
}
```

Since GLFW saves the last event for each key, you just need to see if the last event was PRESS or RELEASE. GLFW doesn't report the REPEAT event using this method, but you can assume it is repeating until a RELEASE event is fired.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little late to the party, but I figured I could share what worked for me. I'm writting in C++, but I'll keep it as simple as possible.

I created an array of booleans with arbitrary size to store all keys pressed.

`bool *keysArePressed = new bool[512];`.

Instead of making a class for (I'm way too lazy for it) what I did was grab if the key was pressed with:

```
void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) 
{ 
   keysArePressed[key] = (glfwGetKey(window, key) == GLFW_PRESS);
}

void keyInput()
{
   if(keyArePressed['W'])// 'W' has to be uppercase otherwise it won't work
   {
   /*Do whatever here*/
   }
}
```

Then call `keyInput` in the main loop before the `glfwPollEvents();`.
It seems pretty easy to do multiple key presses as well.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers were not the root cause of the problem I was experiencing. Drawing simple quads seemed to be blocking the input handling when swapping buffers. I simply `glfwSwapInterval(0)` to turn off v-sync which isn't necessarily a good practise, but at the current stage of my program, I would prefer some screen tear to bad input lag, and that seemed to fix it.

Comment: my screen never tear when i force my game work at 4k FPS without v-sync

Comment: @Fox yes, after writing this answer, I think I found that it was something else. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @Fox Even without v-sync, tears would occur when it sends incomplete frames to the screens framebuffer, which would occur when your FPS is lower than your monitors refresh rate.

Comment: yes i ever saw screen tearing with youtube (i literally watch youtube setting each pixel in like 400 ms)